# ADB device offline on ubuntu, can't unlock the bootloader

Tags: 14.04, android, bootloader, android-sdk

> ```
> sudo ./adb reboot bootloader
> error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
> ```
>
> I'm getting the above error while trying to connect my Yureka! to my ubuntu 14.04 LTS
>   Here's a list of what I've tried already and it still doesn't work:-
>
> 1. used USB2.0 instead of 3.0
> 2. added the rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules for my phone
> 3. adb retstart (kill+start again)
> 4. Tried deleting the adbkey, but no pop-up comes on my phone's screen while connecting again
> 5. tried using as a camera instead of MTP

Although, I'm able to transfer files from my phone to laptop and vice-versa, but still unable to connect through adb.
I'm trying to flash factory image (LINUX) for my newly bought Yureka as per the steps mentioned [here](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/threads/factory-images-and-flashing-tools-official.2178/) but stuck as I'm unable to unloack the bootlocker

Output of `adb devices`

```
List of devices attached 
2a26cfb unauthorized
```

[image: SCREENSHOT YUPLAYGOD FORUM]

Following message  comes when trying to unlock the bootloader:

```
Unlocking bootloader
< waiting for device >
```

Comment: The forum you've linked to requires people to sign up. You might want to add details you think might help the community answer your question.

Comment: Could you add the output of `adb devices` both before and after you connect your device? Also, although I haven't done this on Ubuntu for a while, I don't think you should have to `sudo`

Comment: now i manage to remove the offline status, but it still says unauthorized. though I have given all the access required

Comment: Which version of android are you on? I think after 4.1 or something you get a popup on your device when you connect. Did you get that?

Comment: I am getting that pop-up when connecting through windows, but not when connecting through ubuntu, my point 4 is regarding this. I am using Kitkat

Comment: Do you see your device in the output of `lsusb` ? It might not have the same name so you should run that once before and after you connect your device?

Comment: Yes, I could see it there. Thats is how I got to know about vendor id and product id required for entry in  /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

Comment: Anyways, I was able to do it using windows. Successfully flashed the image. Sigh..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22201/discussion-between-kasisnu-and-vipin8169).